# Optimal Approach for Managing Project Environments and Space Usage in Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to work on several projects, each of which requires PyTorch, and most of them also use some common libraries. Occasionally, I also need to work with both TensorFlow and PyTorch together. Now, I'm thinking about whether it's better to create separate conda environments for each project or have them all in one environment since their package requirements are very similar. Will creating multiple environments, all with PyTorch, NumPy, Matplotlib, Pandas, and scikit-learn installed, take up a lot of space?

Or if you want to fork a git repo and expand that work, is it better to create a conda env for each forked repo and install dependencies for each project?

What is the best practice?

Comment: conda actually tries to download packages once, then links them (hard or soft) to the actual environment. Actually copying files for multiple environments is only done as a fallback. So your scenario with one conda env per project might actually need less disk space than you might be thinking